# How to deploy dockerised react + django web app to google app engine?

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, google-app-engine, docker-compose

I have created a web app which uses react as frontend and django as backend. I have also added nginx proxy to my both backend and frontend. I use docker compose to build and start all of my containers and everything works perfectly.

Now i want to deploy it to google app engine and I have no idea how to do that. I found [this](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/) well written article, but it uses aws. I want to use app engine because its free (for now).

It would be really helpful if someone could guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine Standard does not support containers but App Engine Flex does using [Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes).

Anyway, App Engine Flex does not support docker compose so you need to decouple your app into individual services (react, django, nginx (not necessary at all since GAE already has an NGINX proxy)) by using your own container for each element or use the already available [runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible) when applies.

Then you can connect each other by using the App Engine URLs. This [article](https://medium.com/@rgoyard/how-to-deploy-a-single-page-application-and-its-backend-to-google-app-engine-353ff93bd38c) can help you understand this approach (it is for NodeJS but the idea is the same).

Answer (score -1):

App engine supports specific runtimes, not dockerized applications. You would need to deploy a python app engine app for the Django backend and a nodejs app for the react app.